# Figuring out type of overriden member variable in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a type hierarchy like this:

```
trait Description {

}

trait DescriptionProvider {
   val description: Description
}

object Sample extends DescriptionProvider {
  object description extends Description {
    val name = "foo"
  }
}
```

Now I am looking for a function `f`, which gives me the concrete value `a.description` for any sub type of `DescriptionProvider`, including it's type.

E.g. `f(Sample).name` should compile and evaluate to `foo`.

An obvious accessing method can't work of course

`def obvious[T <: DescriptionProvider](x: T) = x.description
obvious(Sample).name // doesn't compile of course, as foo returns only Description.`

Is there any Trick how to design such a function f without doing massive changes in the object hierarchy (which is already existent and huge)?

I already tried using a Macro, which somehow works, but IntelliJ doesn't like it (in above Example `.name` would appear in Red), which makes it pretty hard to use.

I am using Scala 2.10 and can't change right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your return type with a path-dependent one instead of relying on inference:

```
def obvious[T <: DescriptionProvider](x: T): x.description.type = x.description
```

I made a [Scastie snippet](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pn2tEqTsRlC83UKuw9i8nQ) with 2.10.6 and it seems to be working. I cannot check if Intellij would not complain, however.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add `name` to your `Description` trait:

```
trait Description {
  val name: String
}

trait DescriptionProvider {
  val description: Description
}

object Sample extends DescriptionProvider {
  object description extends Description {
    override val name: String = "foo"
  }
}

object Main extends App{

  def obvious[T <: DescriptionProvider](x: T) = x.description

  val description: String = obvious(Sample).name

  println(s"description = ${description}")

}
```

Now you can compile and run the code. Once you add `name` to `Description` trait, compiler knows that a `Description` has a `name`.

Comment: No, this doesn't work in my case. Each sub class of `DescriptionProvider` is adding different members to `Description` in my case.

Comment: Then try creating a `NameDescription` trait which extends `Description` but put the `name` field under that trait.  Then you can cast  the response of `obvious` method via pattern matching to a `NameDescription`. Bt doing so, you can call the `.name`.

Comment: Mm.. nearly all `Description` fields are completely different. It's used in a DSL which describes the DB columns for each type. I thought more of a function `f` which get's access to the member type by some kind of Magic type class parameter. However I found no way (except Macros), to create instances of this parameter.